# Basic repetition in scala

Tags: scala, repeat, idioms

Based on the first comment in [this discussion](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3087.html), it seems that Martin Odersky

- sees no need for a 'times' method in scala.
- suggests that `for (_ <- 1 to 3) println` is acceptable

Has anything changed on this since 2009 or is this still state-of-the-art in scala?

As an extension, does that mean that `for (_ <- 1 to 3) yield math.random` and/or `(1 to 3).map(_ => math.random)` are idiomatic ways of creating List-like objects?

Comment: `List.fill(3)(math.random)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Range` is still the way to do it, though I would use `foreach` explicitly:

```
(1 to 3).foreach{println}
```

To fill a collection use `tabulate` or `fill`

```
val even = List.tabulate(10)(_*2)
val random = List.fill(10)(math.random)
```

`fill` takes a by-name parameter so it is evaluated for each new element in the collection.